# SSL_verification wrong version number even with certifi verify

Tags: python, powershell, ssl, python-requests

I am getting this error even with certification

```
requests.get("....", verify = certifi.where(), headers = headers
```

with `certifi == 2022.09.24` and `urllib3 == 1.23`
The certificate is reading from a pem file `Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pems`.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='...', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pricing?action=... (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error(['SSL routines', '', 'wrong version number')])"))
```

Does anyone know why this occur might occur? Running a copy of the request through the network tab in powershell is able to return me the response just fine.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with certificate validation and thus cannot be fixed by changing anything with certificate validation. Due to incomplete error reporting (no reproducible code, no full stacktrace) I can only guess the reason, but it is likely a wrong proxy configuration or a URL which is not configured for HTTPS - see linked questions for more.