# Retrieving Powershell Proxy Config

Tags: python, powershell, networking, proxy

On Powershell, I am currently performing this request, copied from the network tab on developer tools

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$session.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
Invoke-WebRequest -useBasicParsing -Uri "https://......?...." 
-WebSession $session
-Headers @{
"Accept"="*/*"
"Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
"Accept-Language"="en-US,en;q=0.9"
"Authorization"="Basic mzYw....="
"Referer"="https://......."
"sec-Fetch-Dest"="empty"
"sec-Fetch-Mode"=="cors"
"sec-Fetch-Site="same-origin"
"sec-ch-ua"="`""Chromium`";v=`"106`",`"Google Chrome`";v=`"106`",`"NotlA=Brand`";v=`"99`""
"sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?0"
"sec-ch-ua-platform"="`"Windows`""
}
-ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

which returns me the response 200 just fine.

However, when i tried to perform the same requests, with the headers config on python requests, I am getting a SSL proxy-related error (see [SSL_verification wrong version number even with certifi verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74318004/ssl-verification-wrong-version-number-even-with-certifi-verify?noredirect=1#comment131204231_74318004)).

Is proxy automatically configured on PowerShell requests? How can I find out what proxy are my requests currently routed to? Otherwise, how can I replicate 1:1 powershell requests to python requests?

I have tried running `ipconfig /all` command and using the `Primary Dns Suffix` field as proxy arguments in requests

```
requests.get(url, header = headers_in_powershell, proxies = { 'http': 'the_dns_suffix', 'https': 'the_dns_suffix' }
```

but the requests just gets stuck (waits with no response indefinitely).

Comment: Powershell uses your system proxy by default (mostly, there are some odd exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

For most commands, Powershell uses the system proxy by default (or they have a -Proxy switch to tell them where it is, but *some* don't and have to be told to use it.

From memory, `Invoke-WebRequest` can be problematical as (I think) it uses the .NET web client

Try adding this to the start of the PS script:

```
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am looking more for migration of the PowerShell Script to python, rather than improving on the pre-existing powershell script itself (since there are post-processing steps to be done on the data after response is returned, and it has to be automated).

On that note, how will I get the system proxy URL through powershell directly for usage in Python's ```requests``` library?

Comment: Can I get it using ```ipconfig /all```? In that case, what is the proxy URL i should be looking at, I am confused as to if it should be ```Primary DNS Suffix```, since using that just led to holding of my request indefinitely (as mentioned above)

Comment: Proxy settings have nothing to do with ipconfig. A quick Google will find what you want: `[System.Net.WebProxy]::GetDefaultProxy()` or you can query the registry.